# Need to do simple redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess

I need to write a simple redirect rule son when the user calls

```
http://www.mysite.com/subfolder
```

It redirects to

```
http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/
```

With the trailing '/', I've tested

```
Redirect 301 /subfolder http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/
```

But it got a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RedirectMatch 301 /subfolder$ http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/
```

Comment: No, still doesn'r redirect. I'm going to edit the question ad put the entire htaccess code, is a big file but maybe it helps.